# Open csv append a row without re-adding header

Tags: java, opencsv

**EDIT:** I've tried overriding the method as proposed, but it adds a white line

I'm using **OpenCSV** to read/write from a CSV file, and I need to append a new row of my object "**Crime**" when a user adds another one.
Until now, I've only found this way of writing in all tutorials:

```
 Writer writer  = new FileWriter(path.toString());

StatefulBeanToCsv sbc = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer)
   .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
   .build();

List<CsvBean> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new WriteExampleBean("Test1", "sfdsf", "fdfd"));
list.add(new WriteExampleBean("Test2", "ipso", "facto"));

sbc.write(list);
writer.close();
```

The problem is that before adding the new row, it also adds the header, so my file becomes:

```
zipCode,totPopulation,medianAge,totMales,totFemales,totHouseholds,avgHouseholdSize,
91371,1,73.5,0,1,1,1,
90001,57110,26.6,28468,28642,12971,4.4,
90002,51223,25.5,24876,26347,11731,4.36,
90003,66266,26.3,32631,33635,15642,4.22,
zipCode,totPopulation,medianAge,totMales,totFemales,totHouseholds,avgHouseholdSize,
100,100,100,100,100,100,100
```

where the line with all "100" values is the one I add. How can I prevent to add the header before the line every time I want to add a row or multiple rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to CSV file without headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922642/appending-to-csv-file-without-headers)

Comment: @Arnaud overriding the method adds an empty line

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend the `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy` and override the method [`generateHeader`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/MappingStrategy.html#generateHeader(T))  to return an empty array.

Then pass an instance of your new class to the `StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder` through [`withMappingStrategy()`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder.html#withMappingStrategy(com.opencsv.bean.MappingStrategy))

According to the Javadoc of `MappingStrategy`:

> If no header can or should be generated, an array of zero length must
>   be returned, and not null.

Make sure you only do this if the file is not new if you want to include the headers in the first line.

Comment: Overriding the method writes an empty line